# PHP как сделать так что бы пользователя кидало на 5 страниц назад?

Tags: javascript, php, html

При попытке использовать это

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){ top.location.href='<? echo (!empty($_POST['backurl'])) ? $_POST['backurl'] : '/'; ?>'; }, 5000);
</script>
```

получаю просто пустой скрин
подскажите как быть

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь интерфейсом Web History API:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_api_history.asp

```
window.history.go(-5);
```